# Where to "install" node application and best way to launch

Tags: shell-script, path, node.js, deb

I'm pretty new to the Linux world, I have a Node application that I would like to distribute through an apt repository, this is what I do for now:

- Put the node binary inside the Node application folder.
- Use [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to build a .deb package which extracts the node code in /opt/myNodeApplication and a sh script called "myNodeApplication" in /usr/local/bin.

The script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/myNodeApplication
./node app.js
```

This allow me to call myNodeApplication from the shell from anywhere. 
The problem is that I doubt this is the correct way to do it so I would like to have some input on my solution, the questions are:

- Is it ok to extract the node application in /opt/myNodeApplication? or is there a better place?
- Where should I put the script to launch the application? I'm pretty sure /usr/local/bin is not the right place since the script is not a "bin".
- Is there a better way to do the whole thing? Maybe not using a script at all?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to extract the node application in `/opt/myNodeApplication`? or is there a better place?

This is more a matter of opinion, but I reckon you're fine doing this. The standard for this kind of thing is the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), which has [more specific requirements](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) for `/opt`, but it's your packages for your systems so...

> Where should I put the script to launch the application? I'm pretty sure `/usr/local/bin` is not the right place since the script is not a "bin".

If you look at the contents of `/usr/bin` you'll see that `bin` directories contain lots of scripts; the point of `.../bin` directories is just to contain executable commands, regardless of their implementation details. So storing a script in `/usr/local/bin` to make your application easier to launch is fine.

> Is there a better way to do the whole thing? Maybe not using a script at all?

You could actually make your Node script executable directly, with the following shebang line added at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253027/node-and-shebang-help-executing-via-command-line for details). Then you could rename your `app.js` to just `app` and have users run it directly... (This assumes it can run with a working directory other than `/opt/myNodeApplication`.)

If you're interested in packaging Node applications as `.deb` packages, take a look at `npm2deb`, it may come in handy.

Comment: Thank you, at the end I put the shebang line in the app.js, renamed it app, and created a symlink in /usr/local/bin pointing at that file.

Works good so far, thank you for the help!